# A Pub Quiz Joke

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, humor

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #49: Pub Quiz Camouflage](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/)</sup>

---

For this pub quiz, I urge you to listen closely. The final word hidden within this pub quiz describes, jokingly, what pub quiz participants are.

Answer on!

> 1. What is the name given to any convex polyhedron with six faces, all of which are quadrilaterals (though not necessarily rectangles)?
> 2. What is the third-largest island of Japan?
> 3. Who is the Japanese figure skater who, aside from being famous for having broken many world records, holds (as of September 18, 2020) the world standing of 1?
> 4. Four of Jupiter's moons were discovered by astronomer Galileo Galilei. Out of those four, what is the name of the smallest one?
> 5. Which male deity, along with his goddess partner, was believed to have created Japan?
> 6. Who is the founder of the American aerospace manufacturing company SpaceX?
> 7. What is the most spoken constructed language?
> 8. What term is used to describe a programming language that is designed to go beyond the norms of programming language design yet is not intended to be for practical use?
> 9. Which American animated cartoon series had a final episode entitled *Things Change*?
> 10. Which British band created the hit song *Everybody Wants to Rule the World*?
> 11. Which part of the human eye, made of smooth muscle, determines how much light is received by the retina?
> 12. The official music video for *Jumpsuit*, a single taken from *Trench*, the fifth album of American band Twenty One Pilots, was filmed in which country?
> 13. Which American band is known for their creative music videos, one of which featured many optical illusions and was made to promote the band's single *The Writing's on the Wall*?
> 14. Who voices the main character of the *Cars* film series, Lightning McQueen?
> 15. In the popular game *Minecraft*, what creature serves as the final boss?
> 16. What is the other name for a 9-sided polygon, aside from "nonagon"?
> 17. Which song by British-Irish band One Direction has a number as its title?
> 18. The diamond is the birthstone of which month?
> 19. In the song *Innuendo* by British band Queen, what was Freddie Mercury's next instruction to the listener after telling them to "Surrender your ego"?
> 20. What is the general name for animals under the order *Coleoptera*?
> 21. Castilian military leader Rodrigo Diaz de Vivar is best known by what name?
> 22. What was the new (and more well-known) name of the British musician who was born Reginald Kenneth Dwight?
> 23. The Milwaukee Bucks basketball team is part of which conference of the National Basketball Association?
> 24. Which country is geographically part of both Africa and Asia?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answers are, in order,

> Q **CU**BOID, **KYU**SHU
>  U **YU**ZURU HANYU, **EU**ROPA
>  E **I**ZANAGI, **E**LON MUSK
>  S **ES**PERANTO, **ES**OTERIC
>  T **TEE**N TITANS, **TEA**RS FOR FEARS
>  I **I**RIS, **I**CELAND
>  O **O**K GO, **O**WEN WILSON
>  N **EN**DER DRAGON, **ENN**EAGON
>  A **EIGH**TEEN, **A**PRIL
>  B **BE** FREE, **BEE**TLES
>  L **EL** CID, **EL**TON JOHN
>  E **EA**STERN, **E**GYPT

and so we learn that people doing pub quizzes are (one hopes)

> QUESTION-ABLE.

We were told

> to **listen** closely because it's the initial *sounds* that matter.